# Changing data frame - Iterating through values in rows

Tags: r

I've got data frame and simply want to change values in few columns from strings to integers.

How can I achive this in R?

Suppose this are my data:

```
data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    Z = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    ZZ = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

and I want to change:

change column Y with given function f [ex. function f change "yes" to 2 and "no" to 1 in second column]

Example of such function

```
f <- function (x) {
 if(x == "yes") {
   return 2;
 }
 else {
   return 11;
 }
}
```

change column ZZ with given function g [ex. function g change "yes" to 3 and "no" to 4 in fourth column]

Comment: Please provide reproducible example of your data [http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here solution using function `ifelse()`.

```
df<-data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Z = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  ZZ = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))

df$Y=as.integer(ifelse(df$Y=="yes",2,1))
df$ZZ=as.integer(ifelse(df$ZZ=="yes",3,4))
str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X : int  9 4 8 5 1 7 2 10 6 3
 $ Y : int  2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1
 $ Z : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1
 $ ZZ: int  3 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 3
```

#### EDIT

To make functions `f` and `g` for the same task

```
f<-function(x){
  as.integer(ifelse(x=="yes",2,1))
}

g<-function(x){
  as.integer(ifelse(x=="yes",3,4))
}

df$Y=f(df$Y)
df$ZZ=g(df$ZZ)
```

Comment: And what if you have two given function f,g and you can't make any assumption about how they work?

Comment: Great.. Sou you can simply apply function to vector... I've been still trying to use function "apply" somehow.